# What is the meaning of "MOKSHA"?

Tags: gods, moksha, pramana, mukti, punyam

How can one realize he has attained "MOKSHA" After becoming free several times, one can remember the accumulated experiences of hardships, depriving oneself of pleasure, abstinence through which one becomes free. if he does not attain, achieve anything that is the meaning of "Dharma"[HINDUISM}?. After going through several grievous and painful experiences wilfully what one achieves as a final release from material aspirations and ambitions, his mind conditioned, can that attainment be called "MOKSHA" in that state of life he is free from desire and does not want to die nor another birth again. I know attainment MOKHSA is very hard to achieve.

Comment: Moksha is a state obtained through Yoga/union with consciousness/Self, hence its also called Self-realization. Just like a casual gamer plays a mobile game for enjoyment, without knowing its coding or programmer, similarly normal people and fauna use their bodies temporarily in ego and disappearing with death, without interest in its maker or purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Talk 502, Talks with Ramana Maharshi, 16th August 1938

> There is room for kama (desire) so long as there is an object apart
> from the subject (i.e., duality). There can be no desire if there is
> no object. The state of no-desire is moksha. Because of duality a
> desire arises for the acquisition of the object. That is the outgoing
> mind, which is the basis of duality and of desire. If one knows that
> Bliss is none other than the Self the mind becomes inward turned. If
> the Self is gained all the desires are fulfilled. That is the apta
> kamah atma kamah akamascha (fulfilment of desire) of the
> Brihadaranyaka Upanishad. That is moksha.